# apk ionic corrompido

Tags: ionic, ionic3, apk

tenho um aplicativo publicado na playstore, feito com ionic 3. Mudei de maquina fiz as instalações novamente e tentei buildar o app com --release --prod para assinar o apk e ver se estava tudo certinho, se usar apenas --prod funciona normal, porem se faço com --release na hora de instalar o apk fala que o pacote está corrompido. Alguém já teve esse problema?

Comment: olha esse fórum parece ter o mesmo problema  https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/release-produces-corrupted-apk/94611/40

Comment: vi esse post amigo, mas não tem solução, tentei fazer o que foi dito lá, mas não obtive sucesso.

Comment: Estou com o mesmo problema há 3 dias. Se encontrar a solução, favor compartilhar!

Comment: Olá amigo, eu entrei no android studio e atualizei o sdk e ao gerar o apk assinado eu utilizei essa versão:
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3

Isso resolveu pra mim, Abraço

Answer (score -2):

Solução: No android studio atualizei o sdk e ao gerar o apk assinado eu utilizei essa versão: C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3 
Isso resolveu pra mim.